# How to distinguish between a label and a textfield in cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, label, nstextfield

I want to have a collection of all of my textfields in my view:

```
for ( NSView* view in [self.view subviews])
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]]){
            [self.allTxtFields addObject:view];
    }
}
```

problem is, that **Labels** are happened to be **NSTextField** too!

how can I differ a textfield from label?

Comment: As mentioned by renfei - just use the `editable` property…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I went by the tag number: I gave all the TextFields numbers between 100 to 200, and check by that -

```
if ([view isMemberOfClass:[NSTextField class]] && [view tag] >=100 && [view tag] <200){
        if ([view isAccessibilityEnabled]){
            NSTextField* tfView = (NSTextField*)view;
            [self.allTxtFields addObject:tfView];
        }
    }
```

not the most elegant but it works with no fear from attributes changes...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the "labels" in the interface builder are just `NSTextField`s with some special default configurations, for example:

- `editable` = `NO`
- `selectable` = `NO`
- `bordered` = `NO`
- `drawsBackground` = `NO`
- horizontal hugging priority of `251` instead of `250`

You can pick any of the aforementioned properties to differentiate labels from the traditional `NSTextField`s, as long as it is *unqiue* in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use isMemberOfClass instead

```
for ( NSView* view in [self.view subviews])
{
    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[NSTextField class]]){
       [self.allTxtFields addObject:view];
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't work - gave the same result: still counts the labels as NSTextField

Comment: That's not the question the OP asked. It's all text fields if you read the question..